# Set buffer content with variable

Tags: vim

I have a buffer `b:buffer` and variable `xxx`. Can I set buffer content to variable's value?

```
let xxx="content"
vnew b:buffer
... " <---- set b:buffer content with variable's xxx value
```

Answer (score 3):

There's `:call setline()`, which takes a List of lines, but the usual way for your variable is to `:put` an expression:

```
:put =xxx
```

This will leave an empty line in the buffer, which you can delete with `:1delete _`.